# Google OAuth2 re-authorization is missing permissions on the consent page

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

When I force a user to re-authorize my application a second time, using `approval_prompt=force`, how can I get Google to show the user the entire list of permissions my app is requesting?

Details:

I have a web application that requests a set of Google API permissions, including `access_type=offline`. The first time I approve it, it shows the correct consent page, listing all the permissions, which looks like:

[image: first time Google OAuth2 consent page]

Later, I send the user back to authorize with Google, with the same parameters. The second time, it only shows "Have offline access":

[image]

Why does it not show the users all the permissions? Is there a way to force it to ask the user for all the permissions a second time? Why does it now show "Have offline access" the first time?

Our users find it confusing that our app is not asking for any actual permissions, so I'd rather just show the first approval screen again.

The full parameters for the request I am making are as follows. URL:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force&client_id=1039955146864.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8081/sync/google/callback&response_type=code&scope=openid%20email%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member.readonly%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly&state=480704597031619284232891277399900450622
```

Parameters broken out:

```
access_type:offline
approval_prompt:force
client_id:1039955146864.apps.googleusercontent.com
redirect_uri:http://localhost:8081/sync/google/callback
response_type:code
scope:openid email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly
state:480704597031619284232891277399900450622
```

Comment: We're having the same issue.  Have you figured anything out yet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We launched incremental auth and this is the working as designed.

http://googleplusplatform.blogspot.com/2013/12/google-sign-in-improvements11.html

The idea is if a user has already granted the permissions to an app, there is no need to show the same permissions and ask the user to approve.

If you write your application properly then this situation should not arise. If you request an offline code (refresh token) and store it on your backend, you shouldn't be asking for it again unless if you need to get some new scopes/permissions. You should use the refresh token that you have stored in the future. If you only need the access token when the user is on your site, you can use other flows to request an access token without user seeing an approval page.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Seems reasonable, although not what I expected with "approval_prompt=force" (I guess I expected it to ask for ALL permissions again). I'll fix my app to do something else.

Comment: "If you write your application properly then this situation should not arise" ...  How can we handle the case where we receive a refresh token but then have a failure that prevents it from being saved?  We're forced to show the user a confusing permission "have offline access" when we try again.

Comment: Yes, that is a situation where we need to do better and show a more meaningful page. We are considering a) show all the scopes again b) show a message and ask the user to just confirm the account they are trying to use to sign-in. e.g."Select the account you want to use to sign-into this application". This can take care of situations where user is signed into multiple accounts and may want to sign-in with a different account.

Comment: I think if you do b) you'll still want to include a).

Comment: This bit me again as I migrated another app from Google OpenID to OAuth.  Grumble grumble.

Comment: I'm at the same point where @FrankSchwieterman was. As of this writing, I can't even get to see the new prompt requiring offline access, and I must revoke everything instead of simply reissuing refreshToken. I'm using gapi.auth2 go get the authCode, but docs (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference) say nothing about forcing the prompt. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You have to revoke the access token and log out. Then if you go to sign in process, It will show the permission.

```
public static void RevokeAcess(String accessOrRefreshToken) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
{
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token="+accessOrRefreshToken);
    client.execute(post);
}
```

This network process should be called in non ui thread or asyntask