# "This app would like to: Have offline access" when access_type=online

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have a Google App with OAuth 2.0 authentication. Everything used to work fine but recently I started getting the following "Request for permission" screen:

[image]

The strange part is that I get this screen when I pass `access_type=online`. Again, this used to work until recently.

What can be the cause for this? TIA

**Edit:**

The requested scopes are:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
```

I have already tried:

- with and without `access_type=online`
- with and without `approval_prompt=auto`

**Edit #2:**

This is the python code I'm using to generate the authentication URL:

```
encoded_params = urllib.urlencode({
    "response_type" : "code",
    "client_id" : MY_CLIENT_ID,
    "scope" : " ".join(MY_SCOPES),
    "redirect_uri" : MY_REDIRECT_URI,
    "state" : random_security_token,
    "access_type" : "online",
    "approval_prompt" : "auto",
    })

auth_url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?" + encoded_params
```

**Update (Oct. 14):**

Even with the new scopes, I still get the consent screen. Recently I got it for a new device I was using for the authentication.

Comment: How are you requesting oauth2 permissions? Do you have an app that can be launched pre-authenticaed from google drive or is it standalone using the api? If the latter, can you add the auth code to the question?

Comment: @daw I'm using python and manually generating the authentication url, see the edit I made.

Comment: hmm - looks ok. I am requesting the same scopes and get this unwanted prompt when launching from google drive. Google themselves are adding "access_type: offline" to the url they create. I wonder if its because the email address is available offline so they override the access_type?

Comment: @Tzach where you able to resolve your issue? I'm having the same issue and I'm not able to find a solution.

Comment: @IoannisTzikas Nope, sorry.

Comment: Does your redirect_url contain "localhost"?  I was having this issue too. I changed the redirect_url to a public domain address, and so far it has fixed this issue. I have not been about to reproduce the error (yet). Not sure if that was the actual fix.

Comment: @infrared YES. It works in my production site without 'localhost' in the redirect_url.  It still shows the consent screen when I run my application in my computer with the 'localhost'.  Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The App keeps asking for permission to "Have offline access", why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097008/the-app-keeps-asking-for-permission-to-have-offline-access-why)

Answer (score 28):

I think G does this when your app requests a token and there is still a valid access or refresh token for the user for the scopes in question.

The solution is to revoke tokens when you're done with them (either on user logout or immediately after authenticating the user) by issuing this request:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={token}
```

You don't have to provide any app credentials, just the token as a URL argument.

(docs here https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke)

I had the same problem and no combination of `access_type` or `approval_prompt` values seemed to solve it. Revoking the token did the trick.

I'm not sure how to revoke all outstanding tokens for your app, unless you happened to store them. To test with your own user account, you can manually revoke the existing token for your app here:

```
https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions
```

Comment: Thank you! This saved me a lot of empty cycles :). The last link on your post did the trick

Answer (score 19):

**UPDATE:**

The Scope for E-mail is now

```
email
```

> Legacy Google+ APIs have been shut down as of March 7, 2019. Scopes
> previously requested by your apps may now be deprecated or invalid.
> Developers should update their code to remove or update references to
> Google+, Google+ APIs, and any related OAuth scopes.
> *source:* https://developers.google.com/+/scopes-shutdown

*-- OLD ANSWER --*

Google recently changed the Scope for Email. You should replace

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
```

with:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read
```

and:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
```

Then the offline access should disappear.

See also:

https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#email

> Warning: This scope is deprecated. Google will no longer support this scope after Sept. 1, 2014. For details, see Migrating to Google+ Sign-In.

This also changes the way the email address is received:

> https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#email

Also keep in mind that you have to activate the Google+ API in your management console in order for this to work.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! Actually the new scopes should be `email` and `profile`, as they are equivalent to the scopes requested in the question.

Comment: I'm glad I could be of help.

Comment: Hmm, I'm using "email profile" as my scope string but still getting the permission request for "Have offline access".  Whats really weird is it only happens from integration tests, not manually.  I'm running the same server environment and using the same google credentials in both cases.

Comment: Hm thats weird. For me setting: "approval_prompt" to "auto" helped, but I guess you have already tried this.

Comment: Looks like they will still support userinfo.email, although depricated (I don't see that warning anymore, only this in the migration guide: *Depreciated and will be maintained and kept available for backward compatibility. Google will continue generating new tokens with these scopes.*

Comment: @dominik 's suggestion is correct. I have done "approval_prompt" to "auto" and "Have offline access" prompt is disabled.

Comment: warning: for accounts that don't have G+ enabled, the https://.../plus.login scope prompts them to set up G+ and fails if they cancel.

Comment: I get 'Error: invalid_scope' error when I try to use scopes 'plus.login' and 'plus.profile.emails.read' instead of 'profile' and 'email'

Comment: There doesn't seem to be solution for this using mobile apps? `approval_prompt` is not available in apps. The new scopes `email` and `profile` don't work! And the deprecated scope doesn't work properly if users don't have G+ enabled.

Answer (score 18):

Using `http://localhost` in the `redirect_url` parameter of the OAuth request will cause the user to be asked to grant offline access the first time they authenticate after each login.

Comment: Thanks. Is this documented somewhere? Is there a reason for this behavior?

Comment: Not that I can see. This has just been my experience using trial and error. Also the `localhost` behaviour is mentioned in a bunch of questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20555351/google-oauth2-re-authorization-is-missing-permissions-on-the-consent-page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28957654/google-keeps-asking-for-consent-for-offline-access-even-after-the-user-has-autho http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28052155/always-have-offline-access-google-oauth-2?lq=1

Answer (score 5):

Tzach. In order to not prompt the consent screen after first login. You may need this to pass the value to the function :

> $client->setApprovalPrompt ("auto");

Comment: Already tried it. Please read the question and the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

I think this has been answered, but I can't find the link right now.

In a nutshell, Google recently made some changes around scopes in order to implement incremental scopes. Part of those changes is that if your app causes a auth prompt, yet the user has already authed, Google has to ask for something, so asks for offline access. Try setting

```
approval_prompt=auto
```

to avoid the prompt

Comment: Thanks, but what is the reason to ask for offline access when I specifically ask for online access? This may confuse the user and might even prevent him from approving the access.

Comment: I agree, and it's been raised to Google a few times. In your case the focus is to make your app not prompt at all.

Comment: BTW I already have `approval_prompt=auto` in the request, and still get the prompt screen.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue.  Although I was not setting

```
access_type=online
```

However, according to my understanding, the default

```
access_type
```

is

```
online
```

From:  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer:
"The default style of access is called online."

What solved this for me was to remove:

```
prompt=consent
```

There is still a consent form on the first go of course, just now it is not a consent form asking for offline access, which probably scares away some would-be users.

I believe the prompt parameter is intended as a replacement for the approval_prompt parameter.  But it seems like if I set it to "consent", that should just mean I want the normal consent screen shown everytime, not the "offline access" consent screen.  The docs here:  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#prompt don't seem to refute that notion, so I'm not sure why it behaves this way.  But at least I was able to get it working the way I want it, for now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know if this actually constitutes an answer, but I've found that *some* users see the:

'Have offline access'

compared to others (who get what I think you want to see):

'View basic information about your account'

Comment: The thing is that I get this screen although I already approved the app sometime in the past. It's like an additional approval.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe it has something to do with replacing `approval_prompt` with `prompt`?  (https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#prompt)

Answer (score -1):

Are you using Google APIs Client Library?

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/

It sets access_type to 'offline' when refreshing tokens on its own

In Python version, I changed line 1204 of oauth2client/client.py

from

```
    'access_type': 'offline',
```

to

```
    'access_type': 'online',
```

and it now works correctly.

Comment: I'm not using this library, see to question for the exact code that generates the url.

Answer (score -2):

I applied everything in this question. In my case, only clearing cookies worked.