# asp.net mvc DotNetOpenAuth.GoogleOAuth2. 'This app would like to have offline access'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dotnetopenauth, asp.net-mvc-5, google-oauth

I am using standard MVC 4 project that I have upgraded to MVC5. The only difference from what standard template project is DotNetOpenAuth.GoogleOAuth2 to achieve google oauth2 sign in. The first time the user registers they will see a message indicating that my web site would like to "View your email address" and "View basic information about your account". 
The browser cache is then cleared. The next time they sign in, they see the image shown below:

[image: offline access]

The problem is that my app doesn't need offline access and I can imagine that some of my users would be concerned about this message.

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405274/this-app-would-like-to-have-offline-access-when-access-type-online) and similar questions where the suggestion is to use `approval_prompt=auto`, but: -

1. I am unsure of how to set this using DotNetOpenAuth. Looking at the source code for GoogleOAuth2 it seems like `GetServiceLoginUrl(Uri returnUrl)`, is the likely spot, but there doesn't seem to be a way to influence the parameters that are used.
2. I was wondering if there were any negative side effects of setting this.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? I am facing the same.

Comment: @Dryadwoods - sadly, no. I haven't found any good solution and nobody answered here.

Answer (score 0):

I think it just does that when your app isn't live. If your app is actually live....I have no clue