# what scope should I use (google login with hybridauth / oauth)

Tags: php, oauth, google-api, google-plus, hybridauth

I am building a website with google login using hybridauth.

I just want some basic info such as email, userid and username but I cannot set the scope correct.

It keeps ask for "have offline access"

I tried each of these url in the scope:

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email

  ```
  "Google" => array ( 
      "enabled" => true,
      "keys"    => array ( "id" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "secret" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"),
      "scope" => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"
      //https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get
  ),
  ```

I have read these two article, but still cannot figure it out

[google plus outh thing](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get)

["This app would like to: Have offline access" when access_type=online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405274/this-app-would-like-to-have-offline-access-when-access-type-online)

Comment: please share the config you are using

Comment: please have a look at the code, thx

Comment: I suggest adding  "access_type"     => "offline", to you Google array and also setting scope as "scope" => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me email" , also I edited out your code snippet, remember to do not share your application secret :)

Comment: thx for the edit. But its very weird, i try with 3 different accounts. Two get basic info, one get "have offline access".

Answer (score 1):

A couple of the answers in the post you linked to pointed out that the `userinfo.profile` and `userinfo.email` scopes are deprecated and scheduled for removal soon, and that this is related to the access_type issue you're seeing. Try using just the `plus.me` or `plus.login` scopes, or one of the other non-deprecated scopes from the Google Developer documentation you linked to.

It also sounds like this prompt may take place if you have already authorized the app to some scopes, and are requesting a change to the scopes used in that app. You may wish to completely disconnect the app at http://plus.google.com/apps and see if that helps.

Finally, you may wish to show the code you're using to see if we can help you find an error there.