# Always "Have Offline Access" | Google OAuth 2

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am trying to get fetch user's profile using Google OAuth2 api. After user authentication, on the consent page, I am always asked for "Have Offline Access"

The URL in browser looks like :-

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?***scope=email***&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://localhost/google_oauth2_login&state=YbzrDo&client_id=asdfasdf-60qhnqf6asdfasdfasdfcopo3plhoj.apps.googleusercontent.com&hl=en-US&from_login=1&as=604c0f3asdfasdf

As visible in the URL above, I have passed scope parameter as '***email***'

[Google Auth API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#login-scopes) page says:-

> "This scope requests that your app be given access to:
>
> the user's Google account email address. You access the email address
>   by calling people.get, which returns the emails array (or by calling
>   people.getOpenIdConnect, which returns the email property in
>   OIDC-compliant format). the name of the Google Apps domain, if any,
>   that the user belongs to. The domain name is returned as the domain
>   property from people.get (or hd property from getOpenIdConnect). This
>   email scope is equivalent to and replaces the
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email scope."

Why I am asked for Offline Access every time?

[image]

[image: Google API Console Page for WEB APPLICATION]

Comment: this happens if there are outstanding tokens. revoke them to solve it. more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405274/this-app-would-like-to-have-offline-access-when-access-type-online/29267449#29267449

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem, and after googling for a long while, I found this link:

["This app would like to: Have offline access" when access_type=online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405274/this-app-would-like-to-have-offline-access-when-access-type-online)

it suggests to remove 'localhost' in the redirect_uri, and it works for me.

Comment: I'm not seeing "localhost" mentioned anywhere on that page. Is the link correct?

Comment: This works for me, although I also did not find any related information in that link.

Comment: This works! I edited my hosts file and added the line `127.0.0.1 localhost.com` and changed the redirect_uri to match

Answer (score 7):

Because you are redirecting back to http(s)://localhost:*/*. This makes sense because any app that requests redirection to localhost is obviously running locally.

Redirect it to a public web address and it will not bother you.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using node js module 'everyauth' , you can override the googles default value by

```
.authQueryParam({ access_type:'online', approval_prompt:'auto' })
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two parameters which can cause this prompt:

- access_type (if it is 'offline', get refresh token)
- approval_prompt (if it is 'force')

A reference about this can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer).

Try to change the approval_prompt parameter to 'auto' or add it to your request and check the access_type parameter to 'online' or add it to your request.

Comment: I wonder if this information is current.
I'm trying to get offline-access. I'm setting `access_type=offline` and `approval_prompt=force` and still no joy.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have registered your client as a "Native Application" instead of a "Web Application". Native apps get a refresh token by default which is a long lived token, for which the Resource Owner gets a notification and a consent screen because of its inherent security implications. Change your client type to "Web Application" assuming that's what it is...

Comment: I have updated the question with screenshot of my google console page. I have used the generated client id and seceret for 'Client ID for web application' only.

Comment: Perhaps you could try with a newyly generated client_id and double-check that the client_id in the authorization request is the right (=new) one?

Comment: -1 answer is incorrect or missing leading Native and web apps will both return a refresh token.   web may need supply access_type off line if you are using a client lib that hides like like say PHP.

Comment: no, they *can* both return a refresh token, but one will do that by default and the other one when `access_type=offline` is provided, I just verified that

Comment: Newly generated client_id and secret also didn't help

Comment: Here's an authorization request for a brand new client with default settings generated by me: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&scope=email&client_id=412063239660-msdo318m84iunoi4b1ppksa8bvj2jrvk.apps.googleusercontent.com&state=sS3_7Aaka9HtSqCFe_4Pm0Ls-aY&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Foauth2callback with the requested `email` scope; this yields only consent to "access to email" the first time, after that no consent is required; no offline access in play; if that works different for you then your platform/browser is interfering