# My app is asking for permission to “Have offline access”, why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth, google-signin

My app is asking for permission to “Have offline access”, why? It's the weirdest thing. I've done a bit of searching and haven't really found anything that's worked. I've tried using these for scopes:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile.emails.read 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
```

and that didn't seem to help.

Below is a screenshot and some of my code to help you see what's going on:

[image]

Some of my code:

```
    #import "ViewController.h"

NSString *callbakc =  @"http://localhost/";
NSString *client_id = @“CLIENT ID“;
NSString *scope = @"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile+https://www.google.com/reader/api/0/subscription";
NSString *secret = @“SECRET”;
NSString *visibleactions = @"http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity";

@interface ViewController () {
NSString *authAccessToken;
UIAlertController *alertController;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableData *receivedData;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

#pragma mark - Lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];


NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&scope=%@&data-requestvisibleactions=%@",client_id,callbakc,scope,visibleactions];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:10];

[_webView loadRequest:request];
}



#pragma mark - WebView Delegate

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

[self performSelector:@selector(progressDelay:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
if ([[[request URL] host] isEqualToString:@"localhost"]) {

    // Extract oauth_verifier from URL query
    NSString* verifier = nil;
    NSArray* urlParams = [[[request URL] query] componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
    for (NSString* param in urlParams) {
        if (![param isEqualToString:@"error=access_denied"]) {
            NSArray* keyValue = [param componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
            NSString* key = [keyValue objectAtIndex:0];
            if ([key isEqualToString:@"code"]) {
                verifier = [keyValue objectAtIndex:1];
//                    NSLog(@"verifier %@",verifier);
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        }
    }

    if (!verifier==0) {
        [self showAlertViewWithTitle:@"" message:@"Please wait" okAction:NO];

        NSString *data = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"code=%@&client_id=%@&client_secret=%@&redirect_uri=%@&grant_type=authorization_code", verifier,client_id,secret,callbakc];
        NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setHTTPBody:[data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];

        NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        NSLog(@"Connection: %@", theConnection);

        self.receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    }
    else {
        // cancel button click
        NSLog(@"not Verified!!");
    }

    return NO;
}
return YES;
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
// show progress
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
[alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {

if (error.code==102) //Frame load interrupted
    return;

[alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self showAlertViewWithTitle:@"Error" message:[error localizedDescription] okAction:YES];
}

#pragma mark - NSURLConnection Delegate

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
[self.receivedData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
[self showAlertViewWithTitle:@"Error" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", error] okAction:YES];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.receivedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSData *data = [response dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *tokenData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

if ([tokenData objectForKey:@"access_token"]) {
    authAccessToken = [tokenData objectForKey:@"access_token"];
    [self getUserInfo:authAccessToken];
}
else {
    [alertController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"RESULT: %@", tokenData);
    [self showAlertViewWithTitle:[tokenData objectForKey:@"name"] message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tokenData] okAction:YES];

    // Flush all cached data
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
}

}

#pragma mark - Private Method Implementation

-(void)getUserInfo:(NSString *)token {
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=%@",token];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];

NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
NSLog(@"Connection: %@", theConnection);

self.receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

}

-(void)progressDelay:(id)sender {
// Dismiss progress
}


@end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: You can check this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405274/this-app-would-like-to-have-offline-access-when-access-type-online/29267449#29267449

Comment: How do I provide this token as a url argument? https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token={token}

Comment: This token is your: authAccessToken. 
You used this token to get user info. 
` [self getUserInfo:authAccessToken];`
I am not sure but, i think so ;)

Comment: First I go here (security.google.com/settings/u/1/security/permissions) and remove access for the app. Then I delete and re-install the app and it asks for permissions properly. Then, I delete the app and re-install it again. This time it asks for Offline Access. Is it because I have an open AccessToken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32210920/why-is-my-app-asking-for-permission-to-have-offline-access?answertab=oldest#tab-top:

> This is normal behavior and occurs when the user has granted
>   permission already.
>
> Basically, no need to worry about it unless you really don't want that
>   showing up, in that case, you need to un auth the users old token
>   before requesting a new one.

I'm not exactly sure how because I haven't done this before, but before you authorize a new token you need to un-authorize the old one.

You'll need to modify the `-(void)getUserInfo:(NSString *)token` method.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason unknown to me.  The email scope pops up with

```
Have offline access
```

If you want to remove the have offline access remove the email scope.   Personally I think it is miss leading to users that you are asking for email access yet are prompted for offline access.   Technically speaking all OAuth2 that returns a refresh token gives offline access so the user should always be told that you are getting offline access but it doesnt.

Comment: I removed the email scope (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email) and it still prompts Have Offline Access. :/ Any idea why?

Comment: First I go here (https://security.google.com/settings/u/1/security/permissions) and remove access for the app. Then I delete and re-install the app and it asks for permissions properly. Then, I delete the app and re-install it again. This time it asks for Offline Access. Is it because I have an open AccessToken?